# Distributing an application with a configuration file to other users

Tags: java, configuration, configuration-files

Let's say I have an open-source command line Java application which connects via SSH to a server. The sever address, username and password are configurable and stored in a properties file so users can specify their own target server. Obviously there are no default values for this kind of configuration.

This is my personal configuration:

```
server=example.com:22
username=exampleUser
password=examplePassword
```

What is the best way to handle such a properties file when distributing my application to other users?

Do I bundle my application with an empty properties file and hint to the user to edit it before running the application?

```
server=
username=
password=
```

Do I tell the users in my application's manual that a properties file with a specific name and specific entries must exist?

Do I ask the user to provide the configuration on the very first application run and let the application write this configuration to the disk?

I feel there are a lot of drawbacks to my suggestions and I would like to know best practices for this issue. The question is not Java-specific and I am interested how this is solved with other languages or frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide command line switches to enter the information, and document them, something like:

```
$ java -jar yourprogram.jar -u <username> -p <passwd> ssh://someserver
```

These options should be documented, and there should be a --help switch to display basic documentation. The documentation should also state that you can omit these parameters if you store them in a property file like you are proposing. For good examples on how to do this you can look at programs like `git`, which is probably much richer than what you are trying to accomplish, but it is a good example of what are best practices for command line utilities.